# uwsgi won't start on Ubuntu Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: uwsgi, ubuntu-18.04

I am following [this](https://computingforgeeks.com/setup-askbot-ubuntu-18-04-with-nginx-and-letsencrypt-ssl/) Askbot installation tutorial, and it goes well till the very end, when I can't start uWsgi with:

```
sudo systemctl restart uwsgi
```

Errors which I get are:

```
sudo systemctl restart uwsgi
Job for uwsgi.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status uwsgi.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

ubuntu@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX:~$ systemctl status uwsgi.service
● uwsgi.service - LSB: Start/stop uWSGI server instance(s)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/uwsgi; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-11-30 12:15:45 UTC; 44s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 19678 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/uwsgi stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7999 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/uwsgi start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 30 12:15:45 ip-XX-XX-XX-XX systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start/stop uWSGI server instance(s)...
Nov 30 12:15:45 ip-XX-XX-XX-XX uwsgi[7999]:  * Starting app server(s) uwsgi
Nov 30 12:15:45 ip-XX-XX-XX-XX uwsgi[7999]:    ...fail!
Nov 30 12:15:45 ip-XX-XX-XX-XX systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 30 12:15:45 ip-XX-XX-XX-XX systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 30 12:15:45 ip-XX-XX-XX-XX systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start/stop uWSGI server instance(s).


ubuntu@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX:~$ journalctl -xe

-- Subject: Unit uwsgi.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit uwsgi.service has begun starting up.
Nov 30 12:22:53 ip-XX-XX-XX-XX uwsgi[9701]:  * Starting app server(s) uwsgi
Nov 30 12:22:53 ip-XX-XX-XX-XX uwsgi[9701]:    ...fail!
Nov 30 12:22:53 ip-XX-XX-XX-XX systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 30 12:22:53 ip-XX-XX-XX-XX systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 30 12:22:53 ip-XX-XX-XX-XX systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start/stop uWSGI server instance(s).
-- Subject: Unit uwsgi.service has failed


(venv) askbot@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX:/srv/askbot/venv$ sudo /etc/init.d/uwsgi status
● uwsgi.service - LSB: Start/stop uWSGI server instance(s)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/uwsgi; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-11-30 12:41:10 UTC; 26s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 19678 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/uwsgi stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 12812 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/uwsgi start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 30 12:41:10 ip-XX-XX-XX-XX systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start/stop uWSGI server instance(s)...
Nov 30 12:41:10 ip-XX-XX-XX-XX uwsgi[12812]:  * Starting app server(s) uwsgi
Nov 30 12:41:10 ip-XX-XX-XX-XX uwsgi[12812]:    ...fail!
Nov 30 12:41:10 ip-XX-XX-XX-XX systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 30 12:41:10 ip-XX-XX-XX-XX systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 30 12:41:10 ip-XX-XX-XX-XX systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start/stop uWSGI server instance(s).
(venv) askbot@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX:/srv/askbot/venv$
```

Comment: Your Ubuntu version of uwsgi starts with an obsolete init/upstart script, not a real systemd unit. You'll need to check your logs; there won't be anything useful in the journal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log file in  /var/log/uwsgi.log showed that I was missing '/srv/askbot/venv/askbot-app' directory as it wasn't mentioned in tutorial at all. After I created it, I was able to start uWsgi.